Automatic Reconnection Issue for Android Tablets with IoT Hub Wi-Fi Network
We’re facing an issue related to automatic reconnection of Android tablets to an IoT hub’s Wi-Fi network. Here are the details:
Scenario:

We have an IoT hub that hosts our application software
Android tablets connect to this hub using the hub’s Wi-Fi network.
The hub’s Wi-Fi network intentionally has no internet access and remains isolated.
We have implemented logic within our code to handle automatic reconnection and have ensured that             all required permissions to access the Wi-Fi state are granted.

Problem:

After the IoT hub resets (due to various reasons), our Android tablets do not automatically     reconnect to the hub’s Wi-Fi network.
Instead, manual intervention is required each time to establish the connection.

Expected Behavior:

We expect the tablets to seamlessly reconnect to the hub’s Wi-Fi network without user intervention after a reset.

Previous Behavior (Android 10):

In Android 10, automatic reconnection worked as expected.
Tablets would automatically join the hub’s Wi-Fi network upon restart or hub reset.

Current Behavior (Android 13):

Tablets running Android 13 do not exhibit the same behavior.
We need assistance to ensure consistent automatic reconnection.

Request for Assistance: We’re seeking guidance, insights, or potential workarounds to address this issue. Any help from the community would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your expertise!
